# Set first 10 bit of int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a 32-bit int and I want to set the first 10 bit to a specific number.

IE

The 32-bit int is:

```
11101010101010110101100100010010
```

I want the first 10 bit to be the number 123, which is

```
0001111011
```

So the result would be

```
00011110111010110101100100010010
```

Does anyone know the easiest way I would be able to do this? I know that we have to do bit-shifting but I'm not good at it so I'm not sure

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "first bits"? Most significant or least significant?

Answer (score 2):

```
uint32_t result = (input & 0x3fffff) | (newval << 22);
```

`0x3fffff` masks out the highest 10 bits (it has the lowest 22 bits set). You have to shift your new value for the highest 10 bits by 22 places.

Comment: Using `uint32_t` is good as it does not assume `int/unsigned` width.  Yet code assumes `newval` is 32+ bits.

Comment: A minor suggestion: Using `U` on the constants makes them more clear to be unsigned (even better: `UINT32_C`. Depending on the inputs, of course, but what if `input` is a `#define`? (better you add declarations for those, too).

Comment: I just tried to show the concept. Maybe a bit lazy, this answer. But then, you could elaborate on the question, too ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Too lazy:-) Just had a very long (and possibly ongoing) argument myself.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Thank you. If I want to set the next 10 bits (so from bit 11 to 20). I understand we have to use bit masks but I'm unsure of how to use bitmasks

Comment: Changing to `((uint32_t)newval << 22)` would avoid undefined behaviour in case of unexpected inputs for `newval`

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert inputs to unsigned 32-bit integers

   ```
   uint32_t num = strtoul("11101010101010110101100100010010", 0, 2);
   uint32_t firstbits = 123;
   ```
2. Mask off the lower 32-10 bits.  Create mask by shifting a `unsigned long 1` 22 places left making `100_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000` then decrementing to `11_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`

   ```
   uint32_t mask = (1UL << (32-10)) - 1;
   num &= mask;
   ```
3. Or in `firstbits` shifted left by 32-10

   ```
   num |= firstbits << (32-10);
   ```
4. Or in 1 line:

   ```
   (num & (1UL << (32-10)) - 1) | (firstbits*1UL << (32-10))
   ```

Detail about `firstbits*1UL`.   The type of `firstbits` is not defined by OP and may only be a 16-bit `int`.  To insure code can shift and form an answer that exceeds 16 bits (the minimum width of `int`), multiple by `1UL` to insure the value is unsigned and has at least 32 bit width.

Comment: What makes you think the input is a string?

Comment: @ScottHunter the question said "I have a 32-bit int", it did not specify how that int was obtained. Nor is that relevant to the question; the question is about what we do once we have the int (`num` in this answer).

Comment: @M.M.: Which is why I questioned the presence of a string conversion in this answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter this answer shows some code which creates OP's example number, and performs the operation. The OP could copy-paste the code and try it out. IMHO this is a useful addition.

Comment: @M.M.: So it isn't relevant (1st comment) but is useful (2nd comment) -- got it.  Good thing OP didn't already have the value to be processed somewhere.

Comment: @ScottHunter Had OP had a decimal.hexadecimal, or octal value of `11101010101010110101100100010010`, this answer would have used that.  Since OP specified a binary, the simplest way to show how to proceed from that was `strtoul(,,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can "erase" bits (set them to 0) by using a bit wise and ('&'); bits that are 0 in either value will be 0 in the result.

You can set bits to 1 by using a bit wise or ('|'); bits that are 1 in either value will be 1 in the result.

So: and your number with a value where the first 10 bits are 0 and the rest are 1; then 'or' it with the first 10 bits you want put in, and 0 for the other bits.  If you need to calculate that value, then a left-shift would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How about using bit fields in C combined with a union? The following structure lets you set the whole 32-bit value, the top 10 bits or the bottom 22 bits. It isn't as versatile as a generic function but you can't easily make a mistake when using it. Be aware this and most solutions may not work on all integer sizes and look out for endianness as well.

```
union uu {
    struct {
        uint32_t bottom22 : 22;
        uint32_t top10 : 10;
    } bits;
    uint32_t value;
};
```

Here is an example usage:

```
int main(void) {
    union uu myuu;
    myuu.value = 999999999;
    printf("value = 0x%08x\n", myuu.value);

    myuu.bits.top10 = 0;
    printf("value = 0x%08x\n", myuu.value);

    myuu.bits.top10 = 0xfff;
    printf("value = 0x%08x\n", myuu.value);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
value = 0x3b9ac9ff
value = 0x001ac9ff
value = 0xffdac9ff
```

Comment: "can't easily make a mistake" --> 1) Bit fields of integer type wider than `int/unsigned` are not portable.  `int/unsigned` need only be 16 bits wide.  - common in embedded processor in 2015.  2) The order of the `bottom22/top10` is endian dependent.  This code may set the bottom 10 instead.  OTOH will proper qualifications, this is a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a *mask* and *replace* approach where you zero the lower bits required to hold `123` and then simply `|` (**OR**) the value with 123 to gain the final result. You can accomplish the exact same thing with shifts as shown by several other answers, or you can accomplish it with masks:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef BITS_PER_LONG
#define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#endif

#ifndef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT 8
#endif

char *binpad2 (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {


    unsigned x = 0b11101010101010110101100100010010;
    unsigned mask = 0xffffff00; /* mask to zero lower 8 bits  */
    unsigned y = 123;           /* value to replace zero bits */

    unsigned masked = x & mask; /* zero the lower bits        */

    /* show intermediate results */
    printf ("\n x      : %s\n", binpad2 (x, sizeof x * CHAR_BIT));
    printf ("\n & mask : %s\n", binpad2 (mask, sizeof mask * CHAR_BIT));
    printf ("\n masked : %s\n", binpad2 (masked, sizeof masked * CHAR_BIT));
    printf ("\n | 123  : %s\n", binpad2 (y, sizeof y * CHAR_BIT));

    masked |= y;    /* apply the final or with 123 */

    printf ("\n final  : %s\n", binpad2 (masked, sizeof masked * CHAR_BIT));


    return 0;
}

/** returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'.
 *  returns pointer to string contianing binary representation of
 *  unsigned 64-bit (or less ) value zero padded to 'sz' digits.
 */
char *binpad2 (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *--p = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bitsset

 x      : 11101010101010110101100100010010

 & mask : 11111111111111111111111100000000

 masked : 11101010101010110101100100000000

 | 123  : 00000000000000000000000001111011

 final  : 11101010101010110101100101111011
```